# Remove # from URL in angular js SPA

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have done, a lot of research on this, I will try my best to explain the detail code bit wise,

I am creating an application using angular js with web api as service, when i run the application i get the # in URL. In order to remove the # from the URL, we need to add the below like in angular config, almost all suggested to add,

> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

so i have added like this,

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router'])
  .config([......., '$locationProvider', 
    function (......., $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        .........
}]);
```

then i have also added the base tag inside the  tag in index(master) file, as shown below,

```
<base href="/" />
```

When i was did this much, i get **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** when i reload/refresh the page, then i did little more R&D, and i have found someone had suggested to add the below code in web.config,

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

When i add this i get error when i try to login, i get 405 error as shown below,

[image]

But when i remove the code added in web.config then it works fine, but again when i reload i get 404 error.

Is there something to do in web api config, i did some stuff there to but no result, anyone can please help me.

Please do let me know if you need any other details,

Thanks in adv..

Comment: Basically you need to rewrite all the non-existing paths (excluding static files) to point to the `index.html` file.

Comment: You mean i should rewrite href="#/home" to href="/home" ??

Comment: If you're using `ui-router` you should use the `ui-sref` directive for easy linking. What I meant was that the server should return the index file for any non-existing path (a catch-all rule)

Comment: I tried removing ui-router, then i also it was working fine. So i thought ui-route is not required and started using without ui-router. Should i use ui-sref now? this is how my app.js look like now,

`angular.module('myapp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {$routeProvider.
        when("/home", {
            controller: "homeController",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Views/home.html"
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: "/login" });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        .........
}]);`

Comment: I am using the ngRoute, I think i should use the `ui-router` Please correct me if i am wrong??..

Comment: @Muli Yulzary, Thank you as you suggested i am using `ui-sref`, It is working fine but now the problem is web api services are not working. Help please.??

Comment: What's not working? elaborate please.

Comment: @Muli Yulzary, Sorry for delay in reply. When i write the code which i mentioned in the web.config, then i get 405 error when i login using `/token` of webapi, when i remove that code from web.config, it works fine. Can you please help me on this?