# How to deal with # in redirect_uri for facebook login implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating the single page application using **angular js** and **web api**, when i try to do facebook login i get Invalid url request error, since my redirect url is having the # so i am getting this error. May i know to how to deal with the # from URL. I tried **enable html mode** in angular config file, then i added the **base tag** also and then i wrote **rewrite url** also in web.conig, when i do so my web api services does not work and i get **405 error**. Anyone can please help me on this?
Either I should know how to deal with redirect uri containing **# (ASCII => %23)** or i should know why my web api is not working

Comment: Can you post some code? Where are you getting the rewrite url from? What is the rewrite url?

Comment: Please refer this link, I have explained the code here,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788560/remove-from-url-in-angular-js-spa]

I have used ui-sref, it working fine but now the problem is web api services are not working